# Colorbox doesn't open on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have strange problem with colorbox, the code I have is like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>        
        <img 
            src='/someimage.jpg' height="100px" width="100px"
            onclick='$.colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_content"});' />
        <!-- This contains the hidden content for inline calls -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
                Some test inline
            </div>
        </div>
```

So, first time I click, it fades the page and opens me hidden content as popup, but when I close that popup, then click on the image again, second and all further times, it just fades the page, but doesn't show me popup with hidden content. What it could be? Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: have you looked at the #inline-content in the DOM after the second time? It may be that the inline-styling of display none is conflicting. I would suggest adding a class to that display none wrapper div and having that attribute in the stylesheet instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I used minified version

```
<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

when I changed to normal version

```
<script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
```

it started to work.